# Cannot constraint button size in dynamic table view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard, ios-autolayout

When I place a button with image in the dynamic table view cell, I couldn't constraint the button size.
I have already set width, height, top, bottom constraint.
But when running it, it doesn't work.
What is the problem?

Here is my scene image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFqZq.png

And this is runtime image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik5Cf.png

I have set the width and height constraint as 30 respectively.
But in simulator(also real device), the button takes much more space and the top and bottom constraint never work.

Comment: Have you set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDImension`?

Comment: I have set it just now. But it doesn't work also.

Comment: sorry, you must set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` too...

Comment: add screenshot here for the added constraint from storyboard.

Comment: your constraint is wrong might be.

Comment: @Bhadresh Here is constraint screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/7NbGTXe.png?1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the constraint for your two buttons :

**Record button constraint should be like this**

[image]

**Stop button constraint**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now. I used baseline constraint before, and changing it to centerY constraint works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set :

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDImension
```

and

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Bhadresh's answer is right.

The thing I was wrong with is the constraint of relation between two buttons.

At first I set the constraint with baseline. But it didn't work.

Finally I set the constraint with centerY. And it worked.